# How to remove gap before the first column of wpf ListView?

Tags: wpf

I noticed that there is gap between the first column header and the left edge of the control. How can I remove it?

Comment: Insert an image showing your problem. Also try to inspect visual tree of the `ListView` to figure out where this gap appears. There is built-in inspector inside the Visual Studio but I prefer WPF Snoop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could decrease the `Padding` of the`ListView` and the `Margin` of the `GridViewHeaderRowPresenter`:

```
<ListView ... Loaded="lv_Loaded">
```

---

```
private void lv_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView lv = sender as ListView;
    lv.Padding = new Thickness(-2, -1, -2, -1);
    GridViewHeaderRowPresenter presenter = FindChild<GridViewHeaderRowPresenter>(lv);
    if (presenter != null)
        presenter.Margin = new Thickness(1, 0, 2, 0);
}

private static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (dependencyObject == null) return null;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);

        var result = (child as T) ?? FindChild<T>(child);
        if (result != null) return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, its taken me a while to get around to testing this. Where is FindChild defined? Is it something that needs to be written?

Comment: Thanks for this I've tried this and it seems to work. How did you arrive at the values to use for the padding and margin - did you use Snoop or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

These codes could work, add it into the Resources Tag in Window or App.xaml：

```
        <!--This Sytle For Deletion of the Margin in Header-->
        <Style x:Key="{x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}"
   TargetType="ScrollViewer">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <DockPanel Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                      Focusable="false">
                                    <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter Margin="0"
                                      Columns="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.Columns,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                      ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{Binding
            Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                      ColumnHeaderTemplate="{Binding
            Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplate,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                      ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector="{Binding 
            Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                      AllowsColumnReorder="{Binding
            Path=TemplatedParent.View.AllowsColumnReorder,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                      ColumnHeaderContextMenu="{Binding
            Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContextMenu,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                      ColumnHeaderToolTip="{Binding
            Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderToolTip,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding
            SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                </ScrollViewer>

                                <ScrollContentPresenter Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Local"
                                CanContentScroll="True"
                                CanHorizontallyScroll="False"
                                CanVerticallyScroll="False" />
                            </DockPanel>

                            <ScrollBar Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                 Orientation="Horizontal"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                 ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                 Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                 Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" />

                            <ScrollBar Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                 ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                 Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                 Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />

                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```